# Does "during" and "through" have the same function with regards to "night"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, idiomatic-language

**Rescuers work through night after Turkey quake kills thousands.** (BBC news)

**"through"** refers to from the beginning to the end of the night.

We also have another preposition that can refer to the beginning to the end of the night, which is **"during"**. For instance: *"Industrial production has expanded during the last three decades."* (Collins Dictionary)

So, can we use **"during"** in place of **"through"** in the above sentence?

Answer (score 2):

"During" *can,* like "through," mean "from the beginning to the end of a period of time." But, [as Cambridge Dictionary explains.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/during) it can *also* mean "at some point within a period of time." So "during," while not incorrect, would be ambiguous in this context.